Django caching causing blank screen on Brave browser
I have a new Django website and have just implemented the filesystem cache (django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache).
This seems to work fine when I use a chrome browser to view the site, but when I use the Brave browser, it initially shows the site on the first GET of a url, but upon subsequent refreshes it draws a blank (white) screen.
I am new to Django and, after reading the docs I think the following setting are all I need to implement it.   And I can see the cache files being created on the server.   So I assume I don't need to add the various decorators in the views (just want it to cache all pages).
What is also interesting, is that the response time isn't that much quicker (from 550ms > 450ms).. maybe because its a filesystem cache??
Here are my settings
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache",
        "LOCATION": "/var/tmp/django_cache",
        "TIMEOUT": 600,
    }
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'strip_whitespace.middlewares.HtmlStripWhiteSpaceMiddleware.html_strip_whitespace',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]

